# asm code for swap_if_null

Tags: c++, assembly

It's a c++ inline asm:

```
inline bool swap_if_null(head_t **p, head_t *np) {
      register head_t *old;
      asm volatile(
          "lock;\n\t"
          "cmpxchgq %3, %2"
          : "=a"(old)
          : "0"(0), "m"(*p), "r"(np)
          : "memory");
      return old == NULL;
}
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the instruction set documentation?  What's the problem?

Comment: I have no sense with assembly, just can't understand the code.

Comment: The function name clearly says what it does; did you read the actual words? "Swap if null" seems pretty clear in meaning. What exactly is your question? The x86 instruction set is well documented as well.

Comment: Which of the words "swap", "if", or "null" are you hung up on? Unclear what you're aking.

Answer (score 3):

The function is doing an atomic compare-and-exchange on `*p`, which is expected to be in state `np`, and the desired new value is `NULL`. The function only does this once and returns whether the operation succeeded.

Some explanation: The machine instruction is `lock cmpxchgq R, M` (in AT&T syntax), where `R` is a register containing the new value (and it's the register associated with `np`, as indicated by the "`%3`", i.e. "the third input operand"), and `M` is the memory location to be modified (which is "`%2`", i.e. "the second input operand", i.e. `*p`).

The new value is expected to be in register `%rax`. This register is associated with the variable `old` in as the 0th output operand, but it is also the first input operand due to `"0"`, which means "same as 0th input operand". But on input the value is not bound to a variable, but instead set to "`0`". That is, `%rax` is initially zero, and after the instruction `old` refers to it and contains the result of the operation.

By the nature of compare-and-swap, `%rax` (and thus `old`) will be zero if either the operation succeeded and `%rax` was left unchanged, or the operation failed and the *current* value of the memory is zero. In both those cases the function returns success, i.e. "the head is now zero".

Answer (score 1):

```
inline bool swap_if_null(head_t **p, head_t *np) {
  register head_t *old;
  asm volatile(
      "lock;\n\t"
      "cmpxchgq %3, %2"
      : "=a"(old)
      : "0"(0), "m"(*p), "r"(np)
      : "memory");
  return old == NULL;
}
```

This function will "swap" the content of `*p` and `np` if the `*p` is NULL.

It does this by using the `cmpxchgq` (Compare and Exchange, quadword [64 bits]) instruction, in other words, comparing a 64-bit value at `*p` (`%2`) with `0` (in argument 0, that is `rax`), and if the `rax` value is matching the memory location, store the new value in `np`, (`%3`). At the end, `old` contains the value that WAS in the memory location if a replacement was made, so we can check that it WAS `NULL` when it got replaced. The `lock` prefix ensures that the processor has exclusive access to the memory, and no other processor can write to this location at present.

This is done to avoid using a mutex while inserting something at the end of a linked list. If you have multiple threads trying to insert, you need to ensure that the end of the list is really NULL at the point when you add the element to the end of the list, or things will go wrong (in particular, the list will "drop" items). The `cmpxchg` instruction is made for this sort of "if the value is this, replace it with this other value".